# Simple wildcard mod_rewrite (NO REGEX)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, wildcard

Please tell me how to use something like to following:

`*\m\*`
to match all of the below

```
\forgemod\m\test
\forgemod\m\anythingcanbehere
```

I would prefer to use simple wildcards like the ones available when [file globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) instead of full regular expressions.

Comment: /forgemod/m/list becomes /forgemod/?pp=main&a=list

Comment: If you want to rant about your misunderstanding of regex and how you don't want to use them, would you mind explaining the [tag:regex] tag in your question?

Comment: Mainly I don't want to use regex at all. I want to use something similar to dos's and linux's delete function. Basically wildcards (*) meaning anything, so for example: *.txt matches all txt files. I am asking how I can configure mod_rewrite to match with this instead of the crazy tangled mess that is regex.

Comment: @john01dav, please try to avoid inflammatory statements. It's fine that you don't like regular expressions and would prefer not to use them, but language like "crazy tangled mess that is regex" and "non-functional crap that is regex" is not constructive.

Comment: You have a none-trivial rewrite rule... if you don't want to use mod rewrite as designed you can instead use it to point all requests at a script file (`RewriteRule ^ myscript.php`) where you can implement, as inefficiently as you want, whatever logic you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?m/(.*)$ /$1?pp=main&a=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This is regex, I am looking for a configuration option to turn off regex and use wildcards (*) instead. I tried to get regex working, but it just refused (even when directly copying/pasting supposedly working codes from tutorials).

Comment: What you are looking for doesn't exist. When you tried _this_ rewrite rule, did it work? If not, in what way does it not work?

Comment: It just redirects to /xampp. I loaded `localhost/forgemod/m/test` and it redirected to `localhost/xampp`. No idea how that happened.